# Cannot install latest version of the package via pip from PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, twine

I have a [package](https://pypi.org/project/sexpr/) on PyPI. Latest version is `0.1.6`.

Unfortunately, I cannot install it via pip:

```
$ pip install sexpr==0.1.6

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sexpr==0.1.6 (from versions: 0.1.6.linux-x86_64, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5)
No matching distribution found for sexpr==0.1.6
```

Package is obviously there:

```
$ pip search sexpr
sexpr (0.1.6)  - S-expression toolkit for Python
INSTALLED: 0.1.5
LATEST:    0.1.6
```

Package was compiled and uploaded in a standard way:

```
$ python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
...
$ twine upload dist/*
...
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

*Package requires Python 3 and up.

#### Update

Directory `dist/` (after compilation from today, not the original upload) contains:

```
sexpr-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl  sexpr-0.1.6-py3.6.egg  sexpr-0.1.6.tar.gz
```

I've uploaded output of the `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` to a pastebin
[here](https://pastebin.com/4ykAAYAb).

#### Update 2

Ok, it seems that [source-code archive](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/f2/97498a55f703a0475bfe8380842efc6375b84ed07d999f479931280a703b/sexpr-0.1.6.linux-x86_64.tar.gz) is badly formatted. No idea why, but it looks like something related to virtualenv (which I was using at the time).

Comment: So from what I figured out you're the author of sexpr, if you try to install it from your github page, does it work as the latest version? Have your tried with other versions of pip?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to install it from GitHub without problems. I've tried with with versions 8.1.1 and 9.0.1.

Comment: "python setup.py install" works too.

Answer (score 0):

For `sexpr` 0.1.6 you have uploaded badly named file. Compare [0.1.5](https://pypi.org/project/sexpr/0.1.5/#files) and [0.1.6](https://pypi.org/project/sexpr/0.1.6/#files). What was generated with `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` (see the directory `dist/`) and what was uploaded with `twine upload dist/*`?

For a binary wheel you need to use [`audiwheel`](https://pypi.org/project/auditwheel/) to fix format and naming (`manylinux`).

Comment: Thank you for response. I've updated my answer with details of the compilation. Regarding your second quesiton, I do not have output of the "twine upload". I've uploaded it yesterday and noticed the problem today. I did not notice anything abnormal, upload finished without warning. I'm looking into audiwheel.

Comment: [See how I use it](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/24475a148b303da781ced12105f231e5c0579981/devscripts/release#L23) during [CheetaTemplate](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/) release process.